# How to automatically average every column in Google Sheets in their own seperate cells?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I have 2 sheets in one file, I want to take the average of the columns in the 2nd sheet sequentially (columns A, B, C, D, E, F, etc.). It would take me a very long time to type out manually because there are a lot of columns. Is there any way to do this automatically and place them in cells top to bottom left to right like my image shows?

What my sheet looks like:

[image: What my sheet looks like]

Comment: Is there anyway to message it privately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a new spreadsheet and call it **`A`**
- delete all rows except the first one
- add columns so you end up with a range **`A1:IZ1`**
- paste this formula into **G1** cell: `=IFERROR(AVERAGEA(Data!D5:D100))`
- select **G1** cell
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- go to your `Stats` sheet and delete all your `AVERAGEA` formulas eg. row 5, 7, 9, etc.
- paste this into **Stats!A5** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(A!A1:BR1, NOT(MOD(COLUMN(A!A1:BR1), 7)))&"♦♠", 6)), "♦"), "♠", ), 1, 70))
```

- paste this into **Stats!A7** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(A!B1:BS1, NOT(MOD(COLUMN(A!A1:BR1), 7)))&"♦♠", 6)), "♦"), "♠", ), 1, 70))
```

- paste this into **Stats!A9** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(A!C1:BT1, NOT(MOD(COLUMN(A!A1:BR1), 7)))&"♦♠", 6)), "♦"), "♠", ), 1, 70))
```

- paste this into **Stats!A11** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(A!D1:BU1, NOT(MOD(COLUMN(A!A1:BR1), 7)))&"♦♠", 6)), "♦"), "♠", ), 1, 70))
```

- paste this into **Stats!A13** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, 
 REPT(FILTER(A!E1:BV1, NOT(MOD(COLUMN(A!A1:BR1), 7)))&"♦♠", 6)), "♦"), "♠", ), 1, 70))
```

- etc. (the only thing whats changing is range after `FILTER` by 1 later)
- a `70` at the end is the number of the last column of a purple set ending at **BR** column (**BR** = 70) green set ends on **CF** so that's the 84th column etc...
- `7` represents the jump eg. to get every 7th value of **`A!A1:1`**
- `6` represents a fix for offset because you merged 7 columns (**`A5:G5`**, **`H5:N5`**, etc.)

[image: 0]